# Mono-Dev ubuntu 17.04 "Debugger operation failed"

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop

Hi everyone im trying to code in c# mono dev (version 6.3 build 863) using ubuntu 17.04

writing a simple "hello world" app

makes it crash saying

"
Debugger operation failed

Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided."

does anyone had the same problem or any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same version 6.3 build 863 of MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 17.04. 
If you don't need this specific build for some specific reason. I Can suggest you to install a previous version. In my experience I downgraded to 5.10 from repository as follow:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF


echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo... wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

install the dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```